# using keyword only in protege returns nothing

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have a class `Movie` which has instances individuals like 2515159 which represent movies and a class named `Country` which has instances individuals like UK,USA,Italy,Austria and other countries. Also I have a role `hasCountry` which matches the countries in movies, for example:

```
2515159 hasCountry Italy
2515159 hasCountry Austria
```

(A movie can have many countries)

***Now the problem:***
I want to make a subclass of `Movie` named `EuropeanMovie` which will have instances the individuals that have only European countries.

After creating in protege the subclass of Movie named EuropeanMovie I tried to place Equivalent To:

```
Movie and hasCountry only {Austria,Italy, ...all the EU countries...}
```

also tried:

```
  Movie
   and hasCountry some (
          {Austria,Italy, ...all the EU countries...}
          and   not  {USA, and other non EU countries...} )
```

But the above using only keyword does not return anything while there are movie with only EU countries like the example in the beginning.

After a lot of search I didn't found much but I think this may has to do with owl's open world assumption but I don't understand that.

If anyone could give any advice it would be very helpful, thanks !!!

Comment: You already gave the answer, the Open World Assumption is "happening" here. I guess you're using DL queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed that's a consequence of the Open World Assumption(OWA). OWA means that there might be other knowledge not described in the ontology (but not contradicting to it). In particular, if the ontology contains

```
2515159 hasCountry Italy
2515159 hasCountry Austria
```

it does not mean that there are no other countries in the movie. It might easily be

```
2515159 hasCountry USA
```

not mentioned in the ontology. That's why the requests with `only` fails to find any movies for you.

In order to get correct answers to the `only` queries you have to modify your ontology to ensure that there are no countries in the film except for the explicitly mentioned in the ontology.

For example, it is possible to add `only` statements to state that the knowledge in the ontology is complete. By adding

`{2515159} subClassOf hasCountry only {Italy, Austria}`

one can ensure that there are no other countries in the movie 2515159.

Comment: That's the only correct answer. As an alternative (I assume that he tries to use DL Query, at least it sounds like he's doing some querying) - a query language that's based on CWA can be used, e.g. SPARQL.

Comment: @DmitryTsarkov, can you suggest in which way OP could modify his ontology?

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding one approach to closing data in the ontology.

Comment: @Dmitry Tsarkov ,thank you very much, very useful answer, after searching everywhere I couldn't find any simple and clear answer like the answer above!!! I  Wonder how this wasn't asked and answered in the past, again thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

With Protégé 5.1.0  and Pallet, I have tested:

```
Movie and hasCountry some ({Austria, Italy})
```

and without brackets:

```
 Movie and hasCountry some {Austria, Italy}
```

and with what I'd recommend as approach - to have `EuropeanCountry` as separate class:

```
:EuropeanMovie rdf:type owl:Class ;
     owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Movie
           [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                  owl:onProperty :hasCountry ;                                                                
                     owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type owl:Class ;                                                              
                        owl:oneOf ( :Austria :Italy ) ] ] ) ;
                                     rdf:type owl:Class] ;
               rdfs:subClassOf :Movie .
```

and then define `EuropeanMovie` as:

```
Movie and hasCountry some EuropeanCountry
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !!!, my problem is that I don't know how to use the above code (I'm new to owl) so can you explain how can I create `EuropeanCountry` in protege e.g what is the `Equivalent To` rule I need to add because the above owl code is difficult to understand...

Comment: Just create EuropeanCountry as subclass of Country and then define it as equivalent to the list {...}

Comment: Ok, but isn't this creating same problem? `Movie and hasCountry some EuropeanCountry` will return movies that have at least one EU country but also it will not exclude those Movies who have as countries Italy and USA. My goal is to have Movie **only** related to EU countries...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I`ll try to see to it a bit later today.

Comment: It seems I won't be able today, but check the [closure axiom](http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/1001).